# Was revival and reanimator timed for Halloween?

Tags: discussion, badges

Was the introduction of revival and reanimator intended to be close to Halloween?

Comment: Yes. It was decided in a conspirative meeting by Jeff Ratwood, Bill the Wizard, Jarrod Nixon, and Kevin Monstrous.

Comment: Benjamin Doomke was also said to have had a part.

Comment: What's "reanimator"? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: I'm glad to see @Michael Myers has joined the Halloween discussion :)

Comment: @Michael: Good catch. It was proposed, but doesn't seem to exist. I thought it did though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You give us far more credit than we deserve. Planning -- what is that?

Comment: I recall planning to press the build button. Does that count?

Answer (score 15):

`[zombie]`: your question is deleted and then undeleted.

`[vampire]`: you only post at night (local time)

`[frankenstein]`: your answers are primarily made up of copy-and-pasted text from other answers.

`[ghost]`: your account has been inactive for 30 days or more but you continue to receive badges.

`[skeleton]`: your bare-bones answer consists of only a hyperlink (courtesy of Andrew the Grim)

`[werewolf]`: you have > 1,000 rep but get flagged as offensive/spam at least once per month.

Comment: [skeleton] your bare-bones answer consists of only a hyperlink.

Comment: -1, we all know SO doesn't care about local time.

Comment: [werewolf]: posts good answers in some tags and bad answers in others. (Would have been more logical if it were time-dependent instead of tag-dependent, but this is the Stack Overflow Way™.)

Comment: @Michael - How'd I do? (I can think of a few users who should get that badge!)

Comment: Hey, not bad at all. I like it better than my version.

Comment: Is anyone else bothered by the inconsistency of including Frankenstein (the creator of a monster) in a list of monsters? ... No?

Comment: @detly - Doctor Frankenstein create a monster by patching together body parts from corpses. If you patch together an answer by copying and pasting from other answers, you get the `[frankenstein]` badge.

Comment: @Jon B - actually, that does make sense. So is the real monster actually... man? *tan tan tannnnn*