# Cannot delete zombie post

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-delete

Unusual problem with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083201/clicking-button-on-external-dialog-using-sendmessage/4083257#4083257).  I clicked the Delete button but that just incremented the delete count, it didn't actually get deleted.  Flagged a moderator for help, looks like he tried as well, the delete count is now up to two.

Repeated shots to the head don't seem to work, do you have a bigger weapon?

Comment: @Barry - dead link?

Comment: @Barry - I get 403 Forbidden; presumably it checks the referrer to prevent hotlinking

Comment: @Barry - indeed, it works if you navigate to the home page and *then* to the image (to get the referrer)

Comment: @Marc - thought I might as well post it as an answer. damn interwebs :)

Comment: Related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69297/was-revival-and-reanimator-timed-for-halloween/69299#69299

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Heavy artillery has been deployed. I think the zombies are stronger around Halloween, and need more ammunition.

Comment: Ahahahaha! I like `deleted by Hans Passant, Bill the Lizard♦, Marc Gravell♦ 4 mins ago`

Comment: @Pekka: That's what we call "nuking from orbit."  Sometimes it's the only way to be sure.  :)

Comment: @Bill yeah, when reading that message you can *sense* the drama of the Zombie getting shot at and beaten repeatedly by a crowd of well-armed people, just to get up again and again, making a leap for one of them....

Comment: It's ba-aaack.  I'm guessing the OP is doing this by deleting, then restoring his question.

Comment: @Hans - this damned thing is immortal!

Answer (score 2):

Give this a go..

[image: Doom Bio Force Gun]

Comment: Bio Force?  That's not what I remember calling it :)

Comment: @Hans - Me neither. My name was a lot better!

Comment: @Hans: It was the [BFG9000](http://doom.wikia.com/index.php?title=BFG9000&image=BFG9000-png). Guess what that BFG stands for ;-)