# Eeeek! I'm missing 650 downvotes, and 300 upvotes

Tags: support, status-completed, down-votes, vote-count

I lucidly remember having had cast close to 1700 downvotes last time I happened to look at the stats, a few days ago. This is a recent screenshot from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88102/change-votes-in-profile-to-votes-cast):

[image]

However, the new vote stats show this:

[image]

what happened to them? Has there been some mass deletion?

Comment: Similar to the discrepancy that's recorded [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90109/please-stop-the-questions-need-votes-too-pop-up-its-becoming-very-annoying/90436#90436) in images. See my comment to waffles's answer.

Comment: Have they just found the weapons of mass deletion?

Comment: +1, i'd still like to know the detail though :D

Comment: Might have to do something with this [heavy artillery thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69301/cannot-delete-zombie-post/69302#69302)?

Comment: Excellent, this also answers my question from a few months ago - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86900/edits-votes-on-deleted-questions-do-they-disappear

Comment: You accepted Nick's answer, but wouldn't you actually want that score back? Especially for downvotes on deleted posts, you apparently downvoted just right!

Comment: @Arjan fair point!

Comment: @Arjan done: ["Votes cast" should include votes on deleted contributions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117846)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The old counts simply didn't care about what was deleted (the Posts they went towards), the new counts do, so you'll see the totals reflect that.

To be explicitly clear since the conspiracy theories are already rolling around:

*No post/vote data was changed* (no recalc, no mass deletion, etc) here, only what "counts" for votes, like most deleted things they aren't factored in these counts now.

Comment: Very good, I think that's a positive change. With all the focus on the importance of votes recently, I think some of us are just watching our stats more carefully!

Comment: Will future deletions now change the votes cast amount in realtime? Or does this still require some vote recalcs at some intervals?

Comment: @Chichiray - it may not be *exactly* real-time (if we decide cache), but the data is not denormalized, so no recalcs, etc. are required to maintain the counts...since they're pulled from the source.

Comment: That's what I need to know, thanks :)

Comment: Not saying it's wrong, but still: why? Especially for downvotes, I'd say deletions are a nice result of rightful downvotes. Hence, why not show that people apparently downvoted "correctly"?

Comment: Nick, just FYI, the 1.0 API seems to still be showing the old counts, just saw it on YiJiang's elections tool http://elections.stackexchange.com. Related chat conversation http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/986165#986165 (I don't expect this to warrant any action, just pointing it out in case it's in 2.0 too)

Comment: I think this is no longer true, right? Deleted posts still count for votes?

Answer (score 6):

Nick / SE appear(s) to have done a 180 and now [your votes are back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/154510).  I suppose you're well aware of that, but this question needed an up-to-date answer :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm just presuming it's a recalc of some sort...anything number wise (rep, votes) seems to get recalculated every so often...is it surprising anymore?

Perhaps the votes were on questions/answers that have been removed (or moved)?

**Edit**
There has been a unusually high focus on votes, the vote interface, vote rules etc etc recently...can't be a coincidence...