# Profile vote stats vs. Voters tab: delay, discrepancy, or just different data?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, vote-count, votes-tab

The most recent update to our voting record displayed on our profile pages now appears to take into account deleted posts, [leading to significant drops in the total votes displayed for some users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90495/eeeek-im-missing-650-downvotes-and-300-upvotes). My total dropped by over 1,000, and I'm totally fine with this because it is a better indicator of the current state of things on the site.

However, I noticed a discrepancy between [my profile vote stats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52738/gnovice) and my total all-time counts on [the "voters" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=3&tab=voters&filter=all):

### Profile vote stats:

[image]

### Voters tab:

[image]

The voters tab still appears to show my vote total *including* deleted posts, so I'm wondering if this is a...

- **delay**, and the voters tab information just hasn't yet been recalculated?
- **discrepancy**, and the update added to the profile stats was accidentally not applied to the voters tab?
- **different view of the data**, and it *intentionally* shows the total history of votes cast as stored in the database, not just the votes cast on publicly-visible (i.e. non-deleted) posts as is shown in our profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch, we were not filtering out deleted posts on the Users page.

Comment: To be deployed today