# Why is the total vote count different in user's profile and on voters tab?

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-count

This is not a duplicate of [a question last year about the same issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90535/profile-vote-stats-vs-voters-tab-delay-discrepancy-or-just-different-data), this is actually the opposite situation:

Now that your [vote total includes votes cast on questions/answers that are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/130540), why are the total votes shown on your profile different from the total shown on the Users/Voters tab?

Vote count shown on profile page shows this:

[image: profile vote count]

But on the Users/Voters/All page votes on deleted posts aren't shown:

[image]

Comment: Followup post: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1590

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, it was just overlooked in the other vote-on-deleted-stuff changes.

Comment: I see it's been done now, awesome!

Comment: I hate to keep whining about this, but now the votes shown on the pop-up at the top of each page are wrong.  That's obviously minor, same sort of bug as the way the week count resets when a new month start, and I assume the counts will be right when the new month starts.

Comment: Now, the total vote count still different in user's profile and on voters tab, such as week. Will it be fixed?