# Why does my over all edit count of posts are different than the total edits count in profile page?

Tags: discussion, bug, edits, profile-page

In Pro Webmasters I have edited 491 posts(All time)

[image]

But when I checked the edit count in my profile page it's 489 posts edited

[image]

What is the reason for this count variation?

Note: It might be similar to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123536/why-is-the-total-vote-count-different-in-users-profile-and-on-voters-tab) question but that question has been asked 2 years ago and they said

> This will be fixed in the next build

But still existing.

Comment: i don't know if this is related at all but here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/posts-edited-count-on-profile-is-way-less-than-my-revsions-count . Seems like in your case it's probably just caching?

Comment: @rene yes. It looks similar. So if I edit a single post multiple times, then those count will also be considered for EDITs and it won't be considered for POST EDITS.. am i right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I researched on the other answer and I'm pretty sure that is what you see or saw, if not caching