# Different Value of Votes in Profile Page (Summary Tab vs. Votes Tab)

Tags: discussion, votes-tab

When I visit my profile page, in the Summary Tab it shows that "601 votes" have been cast. However, when I visit the "Votes Tab" I find that it shows "585 votes" have been cast (*and I'm looking with "All" filter selected*).

Here's a screenshot of my summary tab:

[image]

And here's another screenshot from my Votes Tab:
[image]

I just wanted to know what am I reading wrong in these two values? I referenced the following Meta posts but I don't think I could gather anything that closely relates to this. It would really be helpful if you can please let me of any specific meta posts that would help me understand this.

- [Why is the total vote count different in user's profile and on voters tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123536/why-is-the-total-vote-count-different-in-users-profile-and-on-voters-tab)
- [Profile vote stats vs. Voters tab: delay, discrepancy, or just different data?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90535/profile-vote-stats-vs-voters-tab-delay-discrepancy-or-just-different-data)
- [Where did the Votes Tab go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The vote count on the summary page includes votes you cast on deleted posts, the votes tab count doesn't. Thus if any posts you voted on get deleted, the two numbers start to disagree.

I'm not sure why the votes tab count doesn't include votes on deleted posts, the summary count used to not include them either, but that was changed [earlier this year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/177145).

Comment: Ohh, now I get it. Thank you for the information. Appreciate it :)