# Counts of Votes Cast on Profile page not matching under IMPACT and on votes tab?

Tags: support, profile-page, voting

This may be related to [Profile vote stats vs. Voters tab: delay, discrepancy, or just different data?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90535/profile-vote-stats-vs-voters-tab-delay-discrepancy-or-just-different-data) but that has [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) so there may be some more code to look at.

In the screenshot below, from [my profile page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/115/polygeo?tab=votes), under IMPACT it says that I have 22,071 votes cast but on the votes tab it says that I have 30,383 votes cast.

Is this discrepancy to be expected?

[image]

Comment: Link to the votes tab of the profile page is not visible to ordinary user, gives 404 for me.

Comment: @alexolut I'll leave the link there in case it is useful to any SE staff looking into this.

Comment: I said, just in case, so no one would be surprised.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a bug. As per the tooltip shown in the *IMPACT* box, vote count is the *total number of upvotes and downvotes*. Where as the count in *votes* sections is a combined total of up, down, deletion, undelete, closure, and reopen votes.

> [image]

Comment: You may be right.  I can see close and deletion votes on the votes tab too.  I would be surprised if there are over 8,000 of them.

Comment: How you explain [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN3jn.jpg) from my profile?

Comment: @alexolut I'm unclear what you are trying to show via that graphic, and no one but staff can see details of your votes cast.

Comment: @PolyGeo if Aziz's version is true, how number of ALL votes can be less than a sum of UP&DOWN (178 < 188)?

Comment: @alexolut due to deleted posts. You up/down voted on 10 posts which were later deleted.

Comment: @alexolut here is the related post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/

Comment: @AzizShaikh but why these votes included only in impact section, but not for "all votes" tab? There's some kind of inconsistency.

Comment: @alexolut Agreed with you, there is some inconsistnecy but probably because you dont get to see individual deleted posts/users for which you have made an up/down vote

Comment: I just used a mod tool to see how many questions I have closed and the number is 8.2K which will pretty much close the gap that I had noticed, so I'll change this from [meta-tag:bug] to [meta-tag:support] to see if it can be checked out with less priority.