# Suggestion: Careers use my current location

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs, location

Modern browsers can share their current geographic location. This could be useful to simplify careers jobs searching.

Comment: I don't mean to remove the location input box. Simply avoid you trying with the locale area first, then the region, and then the country. Simply tell it "use my location" and it finds what's seem "best" fitting.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the benefit of one less thing to enter, but also think it's fairly low priority - icing on the cake (whereas we're still baking said cake).

Comment: Did you preheat the oven?

Comment: @rchern but that would be planning! Something they [don't do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69297/was-revival-and-reanimator-timed-for-halloween/69365#69365).

Comment: Preheating? What's that?

Comment: Is it really that hard?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't add enough benefit in my eyes. People could be traveling. Working off-site. Working from home. Looking for an employee for another branch, or a job in a city they are going to move to soon... I can't see how this would give *huge* benefit over manually specifying the location.

Comment: Your current location would be the **default**, you can always change it. Arguably more often than not you are searching for a job near where you are when you filed your CV.

Comment: @Kop true, it will often be useful. But it doesn't add the kind of benefit this function would be for, for example, an online shop locator service.